# How do I prevent cached "Maintenance Mode" messages to anonymous users?

Tags: 7, caching, maintenance-mode, backups

Sometimes pages show up as under Maintenance Mode for anonymous users while working fine for logged in users (the only logged in users are administrators, and I believe I set it so admins always get live pages). The message the anons get is Backup and Migrate maintenance message, even though by now it is running fine.

How do I set it so that maintenance messages are not cached or are cleared out after a backup?

Comment: Are you using the backup and migrate module? Why does the site go into maintenance on backup?

Comment: I am using backup and migrate. The module is configured to lock the DB on backup to reduce the possibility of a corrupt backup as specified in the backup module options.